# Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If $A=B_{r} (x_0) = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: ||x-x_0|| < r\}$, then $\partial A = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: ||x-x_0|| = r\}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $r>0$. If $A=B_{r} (x_0) = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: ||x-x_0|| < r\}$, then $\partial A = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: ||x-x_0|| = r\}$.

How to prove this?

Def. $x$ is in the boundary of a non empty set $A$ is $\forall \delta >0$, $B_{\delta} (x) \cap A \not = \emptyset$ and $B_{\delta} (x) \cap (\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A) \not = \emptyset$.

Comment: Take a point $x \in B_r(x_0)$. The ball $B_r(x_0)$ is an open set. What it means?

Comment: What have you try? The proof is almost coming as you write after making some geometrical drawings.

Comment: Take a point $x \in \Bbb{R}^n - B_r(x_0) \cup \{x \in \Bbb{R}^n : |x - x_0| = r\}$. The distance of $x$ to any point $p$ satisfying $|p-x_0| =  r$ is positive. What can you get with this?

Comment: I'm confused. If I take $x \in B_r(x_0)$, I have that $||x-x_0||<r$. Since $B_r(x_0)$ is an open set,  $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $B_{\delta} (y) \subseteq B_r(x_0)$... Then I can take $B_{\delta} (y) \cap B_r(x_0)$? But the problem is the quantifier, since I'm using an "exists $\delta$" and not "forall $\delta$" @Corrêa

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net This is what I have tried: Let $A=B_r(x_0)$. To prove, that $\partial A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: ||x-x_0||=r\}$.  Let $y_0 \in \partial A$. Let $\delta>0$, lets consider $B_\delta(y_0)$. First, let prove that $y_0 \in B_\delta(y_0) \cap A$. Clearly, $y_0 \in B_\delta(y_0)$ since $||y_0-y_0||=0<\delta$. That everything... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we note that without loss of generality we can focus on $x_0=0$ and also $r=1$.
Then you can take a look at the cases $\|x\|<1$, $\|x\|=1$ and $\|x\|>1$.
It should be clear that for the first and second case you dont get a point on the boundary so you can again focus on the case $\|x\|=1$.

Now take $\delta>0$. Then the vector $x+\frac{\delta}{2}x$ is contained in $B_{\delta}(x)$ aswell as the vector $x-\frac{\delta}{2}x$.
Since $\|x+\frac{\delta}{2}x\|=\|x\|(1+\frac{\delta}{2})>1$ it holds that $B_{\delta}(x)\cap(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus A)\neq \emptyset$.
We also have $\|x-\frac{\delta}{2}x\|=\|x\|(1-\frac{\delta}{2})<1$ so $B_{\delta}(x)\cap A\neq \emptyset$ hence $x\in\partial B_1(0)$.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think so, let me please generalized by myself!

Comment: Why $||x + \frac{\delta}{2}x|| = ||x|| (1+\delta)$?? I mean, $||x + \frac{\delta}{2}x|| = ||x (1+ \frac{\delta}{2})|| = ||x|| (1+ \frac{\delta}{2})$?

Comment: Ah yes you are correct of course, my bad. But with that change it should be correct. :D

Comment: Yes! I catch the idea later on hehe! Thank you so much!

Comment: $B_\delta (x) = \{z \in \mathbb{R}^n: ||z-x||<\delta\}$ where $||x-x_0||=r$?